# Auditing a Single User in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, audit

I have an application that accesses my SQL Server using a username\password. However our lead developer has access to this password and I suspect that he may be utilizing this outside of our terms of agreement. My wish is to audit for anytime this username (appaccount) accesses our database and any commands that are issued.

Luckily this application uses purely stored procedures with passed in parameters when it accesses the database so anytime the account runs a T-SQL statement it has to be from our developer in question.

My ideal output would be something like this:

Datetime | Username | Action Performed

11:23am | appaccount |  "Select * from claimstable"|

11:26am | appaccount |  "update table ...(skip change control process)"|

Comment: SQL Server profiler can filter on Login Name.

Comment: Have you tried asking him if he is using direct access to the database?

Comment: Thanks I'll head over to DBA.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Brad, these are developers we are dealing with, not honest people :).

Comment: @Dan, typo I guess. Here's a copy of the right link: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is what profiler is for.

Comment: Profiler has to be running and is expensive.

Comment: It's the only built-in option I know.   Otherwise you can try investing in a log-reader, if you are using transactional logging.